# Receiving 400 error when querying BigQuery project from Jupyter Notebook

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook

I recently began attempting to integrate BigQuery SQL into my Jupyter Notebooks by adding the `pybigquery` dialect to my notebook's `sql/dialects` folder. However, whenever I try to make a SQL query to a database project (that I am authorized to access), I receive the following error:

`(google.cloud.bigquery.dbapi.exceptions.DatabaseError) 400 Transaction control statements supported only in scripts or sessions`

I followed a link provided below the error (http://sqlalche.me/e/14/4xp6) which states that this error does not arise from SQLAlchemy itself, but not much else. I also did some research on Transaction Control Statements, and those would be `COMMIT`, `ROLLBACK`, `SAVEPOINT`, and `SET TRANSACTION`. None of these include `SELECT`, so I'm unsure about the source of the error.

Here is the code in my notebook:

`%load_ext sql`

`%env DATABASE_URL=bigquery://scio-playground`

```
%%sql

SELECT *

FROM 'dataset.mock-data'

LIMIT 10
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a related issue that has not been merged as of today.
https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql/pull/195/

You can do as follows until it is merged.

```py
%load_ext sql

import sql
sql.run._COMMIT_BLACKLIST_DIALECTS = sql.run._COMMIT_BLACKLIST_DIALECTS + ("bigquery",)

project = "<your project name>"
connstr = f"bigquery://{project}"

%sql {connstr}
%sql select 1
```